# Change background color of scrollbar using jquery-jScrollpane plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I m using jquery-jScrollpane plugin. Using that plugin how can i change the background color of scrollbar as transparent and the Dragging bar in different color say orange?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can modify the css that comes with the plugin

```
.jScrollPaneTrack {
    background: transparent;
} /* or just remove the background property*/

.jScrollPaneDrag {
    background: red;
}
```

or using js

```
$('.jScrollPaneTrack').css('background','transparent');
$('.jScrollPaneDrag').css('background','red');
```

Comment: I tried like this.. $('.jspTrack').css('background','transparent');
$('.jspTrack').css('opacity','0.7');

$('.jspDrag').css('background','red'); But it changes the background of .jspDrag also. I want to show only .jspTrack as transparent.

Comment: then remove this `$('.jspDrag').css('background','red');`

Comment: If i remove $('.jspDrag').css('background','red'); means the whole .jspTrack itself not apperaing.

Answer (score 1):

You can change red background by using this CSS:

```
.jspVerticalBar{
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

and later re-declare your own background to anything:

```
.jspTrack{
 background:url(../img/scroll_bar.png) 0 0 repeat-y transparent;
}
.jspDrag{
 background: url(../img/scroll.png) 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
}
```

this worked for me